# What is this charset?

Tags: character-encoding

I just saw this e-mail address encoded in a funny way:

%6c%65%73%70%65%74%69%74%73%76%65%6c%6f%73@%77%61%6e%61%64%6f%6f.%66%72

Does someone know…

What it is? UTF8?

Comment: It's URL-encoded. See [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/UrlEncode/Decode.aspx).

Comment: lespetitsvelos@wanadoo.fr <- i used [this site](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `%xx` represents a single text character designated by its hexadecimal value. There are two main reasons why this is done:-

1. Obfuscation - an attempt to stop a target address being immediately recognised, for example a hacking or sex site.
2. Extended character set - only certain characters are allowed in web addresses, but often the full set is needed, for example in search strings, where it is common to see things like `... ?search=My%20search%20pattern ...` (20 is the hex code for blank), or when including a referrer web site or user's e-mail address when the characters `: / . = @` (among others) would otherwise confuse the parsing of the site address.

Normally only the disallowed characters are encoded in this way, but some web sites encode everything, for simplicity of coding, as seems to have been done in your example.

Nathan C's link gives you the link to decode such addresses.

Answer (score 2):

It's standard ascii string.
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/#data

but you have converted only a-z chars, not at, dot characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this site](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/index.php) to decode the ascii string, it comes up as:

```
lespetitsvelos@wanadoo.fr
```

there are loads of ascii decoders out there, with many able to detect what format you're pasting too!